# How to package browser drivers for use with selenium

Tags: selenium

I've written a script that I want to give to others, but it uses selenium, which requires the browser driver to be installed with a path address. So how can I "install" the browser driver with the executable package?

Answer (score 0):

I use a folder in the project and then reference by  `./location_of_driver/driverfile.exe` to access the driver.  I have Chrome, Firefox, and Edge successfully setup this way.

Since you did not mention if this was being shared from a repository or custom jar file, I'm not able to help further.  I just do the above in the repository, and anyone that checks out the project receive the drivers contained in this project folder.